# in skype microphone is not working

Tags: skype

my DELL microphone is not working with skype.
i did following
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=6stack-dell" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf > /dev/null
    and reboot

problem not solved. thank you.

Comment: From where you got that those commands will solve your problem? also,a hint about what flavor (Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, etc) you are using. GNOME3 or Unity? 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 10.04? Skype version?

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

### Does your microphone work in any other applications?

Test it by taking a look at sound preferences (right click on volume app to bring them up)
Under *Input* you should see some bars changing on microphone activity.

**If it works**, disable the '*Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels*' option in Skype Options>Sound Devices.
Then open a terminal enter: `alsamixer`
Pressing F4 brings you to capture devices. Make sure that your microphone level is up and is not muted (toggle mute with M).

Installing pavucontrol (which worked for a user in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/990211)) might proveto be  a better option than alsamixer. You can install it by running the command `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`.

**If it doesn't work**, try fiddling with the options in the sound preferences window (if you haven't already). Check wether under *Hardware* tab you can see anything about inputs.

If you couldn't solve the problem, please post output of `aplay -l` and `arecord -l` here.

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 12.10, i did not find microphone option in input in sound settings.  only analog input is present.

Comment: aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: sound recorder application also not recording

Comment: @user179437 Please _ask_ a new question instead of using comments.